# Unable to decode a given code in javascript

Tags: javascript, blogger

I was trying to make changes in my blog theme, while I encountered the following code:

```
var _0xeeb6=["\x31\x38\x20\x31\x67\x28\x57\x2C\x42\x2C\x31\x65\x2C\x71\x2C\x4C\x2C\x4E\x2C\x31\x4E\x29\x7B\x62\x20\x6C\x3D\x31\x65\x3B\x62\x20\x42\x3D\x42\x3B\x62\x20\x71\x3D\x71\x3B\x62\x20\x4C\x3D\x4C\x3B\x62\x20\x4E\x3D\x4E\x3B\x62\x20\x63\x3D\x4F\x2E\x31\x63\x28\x57\x29\x3B\x62\x20\x67\x3D\x63\x2E\x54\x28\x22\x67\x22\x29\x3B\x62\x20\x55\x3D\x63\x2E\x47\x2E\x59\x28\x2F\x3C\x67\x2E\x2A\x3F\x3E\x2F\x31\x33\x2C\x27\x27\x29\x2E\x59\x28\x2F\x3C\x46\x2E\x2A\x3F\x3E\x2F\x31\x33\x2C\x27\x27\x29\x3B\x62\x20\x45\x3D\x55\x2E\x44\x28\x2F\x3C\x52\x5C\x73\x2A\x5C\x2F\x3F\x3E\x2F\x29\x3B\x62\x20\x75\x3D\x45\x5B\x30\x5D\x2B\x45\x2E\x56\x28\x31\x2C\x2D\x31\x29\x2E\x31\x4D\x28\x27\x3C\x52\x3E\x27\x29\x2B\x45\x2E\x56\x28\x2D\x31\x29\x3B\x62\x20\x64\x3D\x31\x4C\x20\x31\x4B\x28\x29\x3B\x64\x5B\x30\x5D\x3D\x22\x31\x47\x22\x3B\x64\x5B\x31\x5D\x3D\x22\x31\x45\x22\x3B\x64\x5B\x32\x5D\x3D\x22\x31\x42\x22\x3B\x64\x5B\x33\x5D\x3D\x22\x31\x75\x22\x3B\x64\x5B\x34\x5D\x3D\x22\x31\x73\x22\x3B\x64\x5B\x35\x5D\x3D\x22\x31\x70\x22\x3B\x64\x5B\x36\x5D\x3D\x22\x31\x6F\x22\x3B\x64\x5B\x37\x5D\x3D\x22\x31\x6E\x22\x3B\x64\x5B\x38\x5D\x3D\x22\x31\x6D\x22\x3B\x64\x5B\x39\x5D\x3D\x22\x31\x6C\x22\x3B\x64\x5B\x31\x30\x5D\x3D\x22\x31\x6B\x22\x3B\x64\x5B\x31\x31\x5D\x3D\x22\x31\x6A\x22\x3B\x62\x20\x6E\x3D\x64\x5B\x71\x2E\x44\x28\x27\x2F\x27\x29\x5B\x30\x5D\x5D\x3B\x62\x20\x31\x68\x3D\x71\x2E\x44\x28\x27\x2F\x27\x29\x5B\x31\x5D\x3B\x62\x20\x31\x77\x3D\x71\x2E\x44\x28\x27\x2F\x27\x29\x5B\x32\x5D\x3B\x43\x28\x67\x2E\x74\x3D\x3D\x31\x29\x7B\x62\x20\x31\x39\x3D\x67\x5B\x30\x5D\x2E\x6B\x3B\x62\x20\x6F\x3D\x27\x3C\x63\x20\x66\x3D\x22\x68\x2D\x4B\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x6A\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x6C\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x3C\x67\x20\x31\x36\x3D\x22\x31\x69\x22\x20\x31\x35\x3D\x22\x31\x34\x22\x20\x6B\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x31\x39\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x63\x3E\x27\x3B\x62\x20\x72\x3D\x6F\x2B\x27\x3C\x63\x20\x66\x3D\x22\x68\x2D\x7A\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x79\x28\x75\x2C\x78\x29\x2B\x27\x2E\x2E\x2E\x3C\x70\x3E\x20\x3C\x61\x20\x66\x3D\x22\x77\x2D\x76\x22\x20\x6A\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x6C\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x41\x20\x48\x2E\x2E\x2E\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x70\x3E\x3C\x2F\x63\x3E\x27\x7D\x4D\x7B\x43\x28\x67\x2E\x74\x3E\x31\x29\x7B\x62\x20\x6D\x3D\x27\x27\x3B\x51\x28\x62\x20\x69\x3D\x30\x3B\x69\x3C\x67\x2E\x74\x3B\x69\x2B\x2B\x29\x7B\x62\x20\x6D\x3D\x6D\x2B\x27\x3C\x6D\x3E\x3C\x67\x20\x6B\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x67\x5B\x69\x5D\x2E\x6B\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x6D\x3E\x27\x7D\x62\x20\x6F\x3D\x27\x3C\x63\x20\x66\x3D\x22\x68\x2D\x4B\x22\x3E\x3C\x63\x20\x66\x3D\x22\x31\x71\x2D\x31\x72\x22\x3E\x3C\x31\x64\x20\x66\x3D\x22\x31\x74\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x6D\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x31\x64\x3E\x3C\x2F\x63\x3E\x3C\x2F\x63\x3E\x27\x3B\x62\x20\x72\x3D\x6F\x2B\x27\x3C\x63\x20\x66\x3D\x22\x68\x2D\x7A\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x79\x28\x75\x2C\x78\x29\x2B\x27\x2E\x2E\x2E\x3C\x70\x3E\x20\x3C\x61\x20\x66\x3D\x22\x77\x2D\x76\x22\x20\x6A\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x6C\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x41\x20\x48\x2E\x2E\x2E\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x70\x3E\x3C\x2F\x63\x3E\x27\x7D\x4D\x7B\x62\x20\x50\x3D\x63\x2E\x54\x28\x22\x46\x22\x29\x3B\x43\x28\x50\x2E\x74\x3E\x3D\x31\x29\x7B\x62\x20\x31\x62\x3D\x50\x5B\x30\x5D\x2E\x6B\x3B\x62\x20\x6F\x3D\x27\x3C\x63\x20\x66\x3D\x22\x68\x2D\x4B\x22\x3E\x3C\x46\x20\x31\x36\x3D\x22\x31\x76\x25\x22\x20\x31\x35\x3D\x22\x31\x34\x22\x20\x31\x66\x3D\x22\x31\x61\x22\x20\x6B\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x31\x62\x2B\x27\x22\x20\x31\x78\x3D\x22\x31\x61\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x46\x3E\x3C\x2F\x63\x3E\x27\x3B\x62\x20\x72\x3D\x6F\x2B\x27\x3C\x63\x20\x66\x3D\x22\x68\x2D\x7A\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x79\x28\x75\x2C\x78\x29\x2B\x27\x2E\x2E\x2E\x3C\x70\x3E\x20\x3C\x61\x20\x66\x3D\x22\x77\x2D\x76\x22\x20\x6A\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x6C\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x41\x20\x48\x2E\x2E\x2E\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x70\x3E\x3C\x2F\x63\x3E\x27\x7D\x4D\x7B\x62\x20\x72\x3D\x27\x3C\x63\x20\x66\x3D\x22\x68\x2D\x7A\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x79\x28\x75\x2C\x78\x29\x2B\x27\x2E\x2E\x2E\x3C\x70\x3E\x20\x3C\x61\x20\x66\x3D\x22\x77\x2D\x76\x22\x20\x6A\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x6C\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x41\x20\x48\x2E\x2E\x2E\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x70\x3E\x3C\x2F\x63\x3E\x27\x7D\x7D\x7D\x63\x2E\x47\x3D\x72\x3B\x63\x2E\x31\x79\x2E\x31\x7A\x3D\x22\x31\x41\x22\x3B\x62\x20\x49\x3D\x4F\x2E\x31\x43\x28\x22\x31\x44\x22\x29\x3B\x51\x28\x62\x20\x69\x3D\x30\x3B\x69\x3C\x49\x2E\x74\x3B\x69\x2B\x2B\x29\x7B\x49\x5B\x69\x5D\x2E\x47\x3D\x27\x27\x7D\x7D\x31\x37\x2E\x31\x46\x3D\x31\x38\x28\x29\x7B\x62\x20\x65\x3D\x4F\x2E\x31\x63\x28\x22\x31\x48\x22\x29\x3B\x43\x28\x65\x3D\x3D\x31\x49\x29\x7B\x31\x37\x2E\x31\x4A\x2E\x6A\x3D\x22\x31\x32\x3A\x2F\x2F\x5A\x2E\x58\x2E\x53\x2F\x22\x7D\x65\x2E\x4A\x28\x22\x6A\x22\x2C\x22\x31\x32\x3A\x2F\x2F\x5A\x2E\x58\x2E\x53\x2F\x22\x29\x3B\x65\x2E\x4A\x28\x22\x31\x4F\x22\x2C\x22\x31\x50\x22\x29\x3B\x65\x2E\x4A\x28\x22\x42\x22\x2C\x22\x31\x51\x20\x31\x52\x20\x31\x53\x22\x29\x3B\x65\x2E\x47\x3D\x22\x31\x54\x22\x7D","\x7C","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x76\x61\x72\x7C\x64\x69\x76\x7C\x6D\x6F\x6E\x74\x68\x7C\x7C\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7C\x69\x6D\x67\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x7C\x7C\x68\x72\x65\x66\x7C\x73\x72\x63\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x75\x72\x6C\x7C\x6C\x69\x7C\x7C\x74\x68\x75\x6D\x62\x7C\x7C\x64\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x73\x75\x6D\x6D\x61\x72\x79\x31\x7C\x7C\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68\x7C\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x7C\x6D\x6F\x72\x65\x7C\x36\x35\x7C\x73\x74\x72\x69\x70\x48\x74\x6D\x6C\x54\x61\x67\x73\x7C\x65\x6E\x74\x72\x79\x7C\x52\x65\x61\x64\x7C\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x7C\x69\x66\x7C\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74\x7C\x61\x72\x72\x7C\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C\x7C\x4D\x6F\x72\x65\x7C\x65\x6C\x65\x6D\x7C\x73\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65\x7C\x69\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x7C\x63\x6F\x6D\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x65\x6C\x73\x65\x7C\x74\x61\x67\x7C\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x66\x6F\x72\x7C\x62\x72\x7C\x63\x6F\x6D\x7C\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61\x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x31\x7C\x73\x6C\x69\x63\x65\x7C\x70\x49\x44\x7C\x74\x68\x65\x6D\x65\x78\x70\x6F\x73\x65\x7C\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65\x7C\x77\x77\x77\x7C\x7C\x7C\x68\x74\x74\x70\x7C\x69\x67\x7C\x34\x35\x30\x7C\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x7C\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x7C\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77\x7C\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x69\x6D\x67\x75\x72\x6C\x7C\x6E\x6F\x7C\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x31\x7C\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64\x7C\x75\x6C\x7C\x75\x72\x6C\x7C\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x62\x6F\x72\x64\x65\x72\x7C\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x53\x75\x6D\x6D\x61\x72\x79\x41\x6E\x64\x54\x68\x75\x6D\x62\x7C\x64\x61\x74\x65\x31\x7C\x36\x37\x35\x7C\x44\x65\x63\x7C\x4E\x6F\x76\x7C\x4F\x63\x74\x7C\x53\x65\x70\x7C\x41\x75\x67\x7C\x4A\x75\x6C\x7C\x4A\x75\x6E\x7C\x62\x78\x7C\x77\x72\x61\x70\x70\x65\x72\x7C\x4D\x61\x79\x7C\x62\x78\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x72\x7C\x41\x70\x72\x7C\x31\x30\x30\x7C\x79\x65\x61\x72\x7C\x73\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C\x69\x6E\x67\x7C\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x7C\x64\x69\x73\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x7C\x62\x6C\x6F\x63\x6B\x7C\x4D\x61\x72\x7C\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x4E\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x73\x65\x70\x61\x72\x61\x74\x6F\x72\x7C\x46\x65\x62\x7C\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x7C\x4A\x61\x6E\x7C\x6D\x79\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x6E\x75\x6C\x6C\x7C\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x41\x72\x72\x61\x79\x7C\x6E\x65\x77\x7C\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E\x7C\x61\x75\x74\x68\x6F\x72\x7C\x72\x65\x66\x7C\x64\x6F\x66\x6F\x6C\x6C\x6F\x77\x7C\x46\x72\x65\x65\x7C\x42\x6C\x6F\x67\x67\x65\x72\x7C\x54\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x73\x7C\x54\x68\x65\x6D\x65\x58\x70\x6F\x73\x65","","\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x5C\x77\x2B","\x5C\x62","\x67"];eval(function(_0xf41ex1,_0xf41ex2,_0xf41ex3,_0xf41ex4,_0xf41ex5,_0xf41ex6){_0xf41ex5=function(_0xf41ex3){return (_0xf41ex3<_0xf41ex2?_0xeeb6[4]:_0xf41ex5(parseInt(_0xf41ex3/_0xf41ex2)))+((_0xf41ex3=_0xf41ex3%_0xf41ex2)>35?String[_0xeeb6[5]](_0xf41ex3+29):_0xf41ex3.toString(36))};if(!_0xeeb6[4][_0xeeb6[6]](/^/,String)){while(_0xf41ex3--){_0xf41ex6[_0xf41ex5(_0xf41ex3)]=_0xf41ex4[_0xf41ex3]||_0xf41ex5(_0xf41ex3)};_0xf41ex4=[function(_0xf41ex5){return _0xf41ex6[_0xf41ex5]}];_0xf41ex5=function(){return _0xeeb6[7]};_0xf41ex3=1;};while(_0xf41ex3--){if(_0xf41ex4[_0xf41ex3]){_0xf41ex1=_0xf41ex1[_0xeeb6[6]]( new RegExp(_0xeeb6[8]+_0xf41ex5(_0xf41ex3)+_0xeeb6[8],_0xeeb6[9]),_0xf41ex4[_0xf41ex3])}};return _0xf41ex1;}(_0xeeb6[0],62,118,_0xeeb6[3][_0xeeb6[2]](_0xeeb6[1]),0,{}));
```

A code all written in a single line, a variable name declared in the form I cannot guess, and a function following it. I fail to understand what is this line of code actually doing, and what are the intentions of the coder while he writes this code. Or may be is it some style I am completely unaware of?

I will be really thankful to anyone who can provide me with any slight idea to this.

Comment: My guess is you were hacked and this is some kind of obfuscated backdoor.

Comment: Coder writes it normally...then obfuscates it with external tools. You won't easily decode it which is the whole point of obfuscation

Comment: I've seen this type of obfuscation on sites which have been compromised. The hacker uses such techniques to make his attack less obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obfuscated code as melponene suggested. There are online services to beautify complicated codes like [this](http://www.jsnice.org/) one, and for the hax codes [this](http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/) one, yet not enough to fully reverse it.

Though the code is not too long to deobfuscate manually.

```
/** @type {Array} */
var myArray = ['18 1g(W,B,1e,q,L,N,1N){b l=1e;b B=B;b q=q;b L=L;b N=N;b c=O.1c(W);b g=c.T("g");b U=c.G.Y(/<g.*?>/13,\'\').Y(/<F.*?>/13,\'\');b E=U.D(/<R\\s*\\/?>/);b u=E[0]+E.V(1,-1).1M(\'<R>\')+E.V(-1);b d=1L 1K();d[0]="1G";d[1]="1E";d[2]="1B";d[3]="1u";d[4]="1s";d[5]="1p";d[6]="1o";d[7]="1n";d[8]="1m";d[9]="1l";d[10]="1k";d[11]="1j";b n=d[q.D(\'/\')[0]];b 1h=q.D(\'/\')[1];b 1w=q.D(\'/\')[2];C(g.t==1){b 19=g[0].k;b o=\'<c f="h-K"><a j="\'+l+\'"><g 16="1i" 15="14" k="\'+19+\'"></a></c>\';b r=o+\'<c f="h-z">\'+y(u,x)+\'...<p> <a f="w-v" j="\'+l+\'">A H...</a></p></c>\'}M{C(g.t>1){b m=\'\';Q(b i=0;i<g.t;i++){b m=m+\'<m><g k="\'+g[i].k+\'"></m>\'}b o=\'<c f="h-K"><c f="1q-1r"><1d f="1t">\'+m+\'</1d></c></c>\';b r=o+\'<c f="h-z">\'+y(u,x)+\'...<p> <a f="w-v" j="\'+l+\'">A H...</a></p></c>\'}M{b P=c.T("F");C(P.t>=1){b 1b=P[0].k;b o=\'<c f="h-K"><F 16="1v%" 15="14" 1f="1a" k="\'+1b+\'" 1x="1a"></F></c>\';b r=o+\'<c f="h-z">\'+y(u,x)+\'...<p> <a f="w-v" j="\'+l+\'">A H...</a></p></c>\'}M{b r=\'<c f="h-z">\'+y(u,x)+\'...<p> <a f="w-v" j="\'+l+\'">A H...</a></p></c>\'}}}c.G=r;c.1y.1z="1A";b I=O.1C("1D");Q(b i=0;i<I.t;i++){I[i].G=\'\'}}17.1F=18(){b e=O.1c("1H");C(e==1I){17.1J.j="12://Z.X.S/"}e.J("j","12://Z.X.S/");e.J("1O","1P");e.J("B","1Q 1R 1S");e.G="1T"}', 
"|", 
"split", 
"|||||||||||var|div|month||class|img|post||href|src|posturl|li||thumb||date|summary1||length|content|link|more|65|stripHtmlTags|entry|Read|title|if|split|arr|iframe|innerHTML|More|elem|setAttribute|image|comment|else|tag|document|frame|for|br|com|getElementsByTagName|content1|slice|pID|themexpose|replace|www|||http|ig|450|height|width|window|function|imgurl|no|iframe1|getElementById|ul|url|frameborder|createSummaryAndThumb|date1|675|Dec|Nov|Oct|Sep|Aug|Jul|Jun|bx|wrapper|May|bxslider|Apr|100|year|scrolling|style|display|block|Mar|getElementsByClassName|separator|Feb|onload|Jan|mycontent|null|location|Array|new|join|author|ref|dofollow|Free|Blogger|Templates|ThemeXpose",
"", 
"fromCharCode", 
"replace", 
"\\w+",
"\\b",
"g"];
eval(function(el, a, key, $cookies, e, obj) {
  /**
   * @param {number} c
   * @return {?}
   */
  e = function(c) {
    return(c < a ? myArray[4] : e(parseInt(c / a))) + ((c = c % a) > 35 ? String[myArray[5]](c + 29) : c.toString(36));
  };
  if (!myArray[4][myArray[6]](/^/, String)) {
    for (;key--;) {
      obj[e(key)] = $cookies[key] || e(key);
    }
    /** @type {Array} */
    $cookies = [function(implementation) {
      return obj[implementation];
    }];
    /**
     * @return {?}
     */
    e = function() {
      return myArray[7];
    };
    /** @type {number} */
    key = 1;
  }
  for (;key--;) {
    if ($cookies[key]) {
      el = el[myArray[6]](new RegExp(myArray[8] + e(key) + myArray[8], myArray[9]), $cookies[key]);
    }
  }
  return el;
}(myArray[0], 62, 118, myArray[3][myArray[2]](myArray[1]), 0, {}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. But In what way can this code affect the blog, I wonder.

Comment: Given the keywords in the array, it may open an iframe and load into it or redirect to any website which they probably want to create traffic.

Comment: If you replace the `eval` in the original code with `console.log` you get a proper code with original names and variables. (Cant copy it here, too long). Looking at the code it appears that it is simply to dynamically load some styling. Nothing to be worried about.

Answer (score 2):

The backslash is Javascript's [escape character](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes). You can simply assign a string of escaped characters to a variable, then write the variable to the console to see the translation.  For example, the first string in your code above translates to the following (run through jsbeautifier.org also):

```
09: 23: 13.657 18 1 g(W, B, 1e, q, L, N, 1 N) {
    b l = 1e;
    b B = B;
    b q = q;
    b L = L;
    b N = N;
    b c = O .1 c(W);
    b g = c.T("g");
    b U = c.G.Y(/<g.*?>/
        13, '').Y(/<F.*?>/
        13, '');
    b E = U.D(/<R\s*\/?>/);
    b u = E[0] + E.V(1, -1) .1 M('<R>') + E.V(-1);
    b d = 1 L 1 K();
    d[0] = "1G";
    d[1] = "1E";
    d[2] = "1B";
    d[3] = "1u";
    d[4] = "1s";
    d[5] = "1p";
    d[6] = "1o";
    d[7] = "1n";
    d[8] = "1m";
    d[9] = "1l";
    d[10] = "1k";
    d[11] = "1j";
    b n = d[q.D('/')[0]];
    b 1 h = q.D('/')[1];
    b 1 w = q.D('/')[2];
    C(g.t == 1) {
        b 19 = g[0].k;
        b o = '<c f="h-K"><a j="' + l + '"><g 16="1i" 15="14" k="' + 19 + '"></a></c>';
        b r = o + '<c f="h-z">' + y(u, x) + '...<p> <a f="w-v" j="' + l + '">A H...</a></p></c>'
    }
    M {
        C(g.t > 1) {
            b m = '';
            Q(b i = 0; i < g.t; i++) {
                b m = m + '<m><g k="' + g[i].k + '"></m>'
            }
            b o = '<c f="h-K"><c f="1q-1r"><1d f="1t">' + m + '</1d></c></c>';
            b r = o + '<c f="h-z">' + y(u, x) + '...<p> <a f="w-v" j="' + l + '">A H...</a></p></c>'
        }
        M {
            b P = c.T("F");
            C(P.t >= 1) {
                b 1 b = P[0].k;
                b o = '<c f="h-K"><F 16="1v%" 15="14" 1f="1a" k="' + 1 b + '" 1x="1a"></F></c>';
                b r = o + '<c f="h-z">' + y(u, x) + '...<p> <a f="w-v" j="' + l + '">A H...</a></p></c>'
            }
            M {
                b r = '<c f="h-z">' + y(u, x) + '...<p> <a f="w-v" j="' + l + '">A H...</a></p></c>'
            }
        }
    }
    c.G = r;
    c .1 y .1 z = "1A";
    b I = O .1 C("1D");
    Q(b i = 0; i < I.t; i++) {
        I[i].G = ''
    }
}
17.1 F = 18() {
    b e = O .1 c("1H");
    C(e == 1 I) {
        17.1 J.j = "12://Z.X.S/"
    }
    e.J("j", "12://Z.X.S/");
    e.J("1O", "1P");
    e.J("B", "1Q 1R 1S");
    e.G = "1T"
}
1 _display: 47: 1
```

Still not very easy to understand, but at least you can see that it's javascript code, probably malicious.

Comment: Seriously, a downvote? why??

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. However this does not give me any clue as to what this code might be doing.  It might be malicious, but if I remove it, my blog data disappears.